# what is difference between writing oracle services vs using oraclize in corda?

Tags: corda

I was reading about oracles in corda https://docs.corda.net/oracles.html , https://docs.oraclize.it/#c-corda-details, could not really understand the difference between two, when to use oraclize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracles are a general-purpose concept in Corda whereby a trusted third-party (the *oracle*) attests to whether a piece of data is correct (optionally, they can also provide the piece of data they are attesting to). You can use an oracle to assert that a given company is bankrupt, or that a natural catastrophe happened, or the truthfulness of any other other-ledger fact.

Oraclize, to my understanding, is a special-purpose oracle for trusted computation.